# angulars, directive, force ngModelCtrl.$parsers

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-model

I have a custom *directive* on that change the view value add classes to an `input:text` based on his value.

```
restrict: 'A',
require : 'ngModel',
link : function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
  function apply(input) {
    // Simplified ..
    if ( input!=='Ooops' && isNaN(parseFloat(input) ) {
      modelCtrl.$setViewValue('Ooops'); 
      element.addClass('is-nan');
      return undefined;
    }
  }

  modelCtrl.$parsers.push(apply);
}
```

It works fine when I edit the value. However I would like to apply the same logic when the element is bound by Angular so that the classes and view values are set.

Basically I would like to call `apply` when the directive is linked. So I have tried to add `apply(element.val())` at the end of the `link` function but the `element.val()` is always empty.

I think I should use another lifecycle hook to call this method but cannot find it. A possible solution can be to use `compile` instead of `link` but since I don't do DOM transformation, this should not be required.

I have tried `modelCtrl.$observe('ngModel', ..)` but again, the input value is empty.

How can I apply view logic when a directive is linked ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using $observe works fine.

```
attrs.$observe('ngModel', function(value){
  apply(modelCtrl.$modelValue);
});
```

(My `apply` function was wrong and returned 'undefined' for all values.)